# Solving the Price is Right

Tags: python, bayesian, statsmodels, pymc

In [Chapter 5](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/blob/master/Chapter5_LossFunctions/LossFunctions.ipynb) of [Probabilistic Programming for Hackers](https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers), the author proposes the following solution to an instance of [The Price is Right](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_price_is_right), where the goal is to estimate the **posterior** of the price of the **full** showcase.

As a a contestant of the show, all you have is an estimate of the full price of the showcase based on historical data of the show, and your own estimates of the price of the items included in the showcase.

The chapter of the book is based on [this post](http://camdp.com/blogs/how-solve-price-rights-showdown), and the code for the solution is shown below:

```
import pymc as pm

# Our belief of the full price of the showcase, based on our analysis of 
# historical data from previous episodes:
mu_prior   = 35000
std_prior  = 7500
true_price = pm.Normal("true_price", mu_prior, 1.0 / std_prior ** 2)

# Our beliefs about the price of two items in the showcase:
prize_1 = pm.Normal("snowblower",      3000, 1.0 / (500  ** 2))
prize_2 = pm.Normal("trip_to_toronto", 5000, 1.0 / (3000 ** 2))
price_estimate = prize_1 + prize_2

# The model that relates our three priors:
@pm.potential
def error(true_price=true_price, price_estimate=price_estimate):
        return pm.normal_like(true_price, price_estimate, 1 / (3e3) ** 2)

# Solving for the final price of the full showcase
mcmc = pm.MCMC([true_price, prize_1, prize_2, price_estimate, error])
mcmc.sample(50000, 10000)

trace_of_posterior_of_price_of_suite = mcmc.trace("true_price")[:]
```

which results in:

[image]

My questions are:

1. What is the Bayesian formulation of this problem? How can the author use a likelihood function to connect the priors and get a posterior?
2. How does [`pymc`](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc) interpret the definition of the `error` `potential` in the code above? In the [statistical graphical models literature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_random_field), a potential is usually a factor (i.e. a product term) in the factorization of some distribution. What distribution (i.e. what variables) is `potential` referring to in this case?
3. Since the author uses the PyMC function [`normal_like`](http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/distributions.html) in the code, does `PyMC` assume that you want to maximize this likelihood function? (if not, what role does it play?). The author seems to be using `true_price` as the observed data, and `price_estimate` as the `mu` in the normal likelihood function. Is this right? If so, what is the rationale of this?

Comment: Hey there! Question 1 sounds like it belongs on Cross Validated. http://stats.stackexchange.com/